# Angular 2 sidebar component not working on route navigate

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router

**Sidebar component is not responding properly when I navigate Internally**

When I run `onSubmit` from my login.component.ts it goes to dashboard/home, 'home' view works fine and My sidebar component loads too but when I click sidebar-items, routerLink doesn't work, and neither the dropdown.

On my `login,component.ts` I have made a simple authenticate, which when successful will go to the dashboard route which has

```
onSubmit(values){
    this.http.post('/user/authenticate', loginObj)
      .map((res) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res)=> {
        if(res.success == true){
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        } else {
          ....
        }
}
```

and in my **dashboard.component.html**

```
<div id="wrapper" >
  <app-sidebar ></app-sidebar>
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
         <app-header></app-header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
</div>
```

But the main problem is that when i navigate to this route, my Sidebar Component doesn't render and links don't work. I have tried even ngZone on my login submission

```
this.zone.run(() => {
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
});
```

While this is my **app.modules.ts**

```
//setting up routes

const ROUTES = [
{
  path:'',
  redirectTo:'login',
  pathMatch:'full'
},
 {
   path:'login',
  component:LoginComponent
},{
  path:'dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent,
  children:[
{
  path:'contacts',
  component:ContactsComponent
},{
  path:'home',
  component:HomeComponent,
}]
}];
```

and for my **app.component.ts**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But it doesn't even work, I have tried many solutions and check web, can't find the proper answer.  The issue is my sidebar-component doesn't work

**Expected behavior**

I want when I navigate internally to my dashboard route, my component should work properly and be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this script inside sidebar component...and then try loading..

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      const trees: any = $('[data-widget="tree"]');
      trees.tree();
    });
  }
```

Comment: While it may answer the question, you should add an explanation with your answer. What was the problem ? How your answer is supposed to solved the problem ?

Comment: the problem with my sidebar was... the page needs to be reloaded to work sidebar properly...
earlier when clicking on a sidebar section item it is not opening its subsections...page needs to be reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not post your component code. I'm assuming that http post is from your Login Component. I believe the issue is your placement of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. It should be placed in the html of the component where you have `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);`. In your case, the Login Component.

Comment: Please check the above updated code, my side-bar component doesn't load routerLink when i click netiher dropdown works, but normally when site reloads it works fine,

Comment: Not sure I understand the exact issue here. Can you create a plunker with your code please?